# Rad combo box multi select checkboxes text?

Tags: asp.net, radgrid, radcombobox

I am using the following rad  combobox in my rad grid edit form template:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcmbGroundPlan" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true"   Text='<%# Bind("Fd_Groundplan") %>'  Width="250">
                                                <Items>
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="H" /> 
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="U" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="T" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="L" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="cruciform" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="T" />                                            
                                                </Items>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

I am using rad grid AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" and everything works fine  as long as the width of the radcombox is 650 px. But if I reduce the width and the selected checkboxes are more, the text changes to number of items checked like 3 items checked or 4 items checked and this string is being inserted to my db instead of the actual selected items. How can I avoid this. Do i have to always keep on increasing my rad combo box width.  Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following property of the rad combo box 
CheckedItemsTexts="DisplayAllInInput" I am able to get my desired solution.